# VMWare Tools fails to download and install in VM Player (64 bit) on Slackware 14 (64 bit)

Tags: linux, 64-bit, vmware

I have installed VMWare Player from the website, and have an Ubuntu machine running. My main issue is with VMWare Tools, and whenever I try to install, it fails. First, VMPlayer asks me to download and install the latest. I hit accept, and a dialog that is unreadable appears that asks for my password. Once I put it in, it attempts to download but then fails, and outputs an unreadable error message. The screenshots are attached below.

I am using Slackware 14, 64 bit, and VMPlayer 6.0 64 bit.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNnPd.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEyVD.png]

Comment: Are you identifying the correct OS in the virtual machine properties within VMware Player?

Comment: Yes. This seems to be an issue with downloading and installing VMTools for the host... before it can be placed into the Guest.

Comment: Are you running VMware Player as an admin level user account?